# Any Difference Between Dates Exceeds a Threshold

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe column , where every row contains a list of dates.
I want to create a flag that identifies if any of the date in the list is 7 day apart from
"any" other date

e.g.

```
list = ['2019-10-22','2019-10-24','2019-10-29']
```

this should result in false as last (element) date is more than 7 days apart from at-least one of other dates

This situation repeats in every row of the data frame

Thanks

Comment: is it important to you if the date is before or after another? Btw. please don't redefine the built-in `list`.

Comment: no, just the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another option using a function and subsequent `apply` with a `lambda` expression. The logic is basically the same as @ScootCork uses in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62916069/10197418) (`np.ptp`), only that the lists are not exploded. This should be slightly better in performace terms.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def check_in_range(dates, maxdelta):
    dti = pd.to_datetime(dates)
    return np.absolute(np.ptp(dti.values).astype(np.float) / 1e9) <= maxdelta

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':[['2019-10-22','2019-10-24','2019-10-29', '2019-10-21'],
                            ['2019-10-23','2019-10-20','2019-10-12'],
                            ['2019-10-22','2019-10-24','2019-10-29']]})

df['inrange'] = df['dates'].apply(lambda r: check_in_range(r, 86400*7))
# df['inrange']
# 0    False
# 1    False
# 2     True
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be using [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), cast to `datetime` and aggregate using [`np.ptp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html). I've created a small test DF to run this on.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'something': [1,2],
    'dates':[['2019-10-22','2019-10-24','2019-10-29'], ['2019-10-21','2019-10-12','2019-10-19']]})

df['sevendays'] = df.dates.explode().astype('datetime64[ns]').groupby(level=0).agg(np.ptp).dt.days <= 7


print(df)

   something                                 dates  sevendays
0          1  [2019-10-22, 2019-10-24, 2019-10-29]       True
1          2  [2019-10-21, 2019-10-12, 2019-10-19]      False
```

In your question you mention both 7 days and more than 7 days as the cutoff point. Currently it will be `False` for more than 7 days, you can adjust the solution depending on your need.